# How to implement list comprehensions when there are multiple nested if conditions

Tags: python

I am always confused when it comes to list comprehensions especially with these nested if-else. How can I implement this part of the code using list comprehension

```
for i in range(len(s1)):
   if i % 2 == 0:
      if ord(s1[i]) == 122:
         s3 += chr(97)
      else:
         s3 += chr(ord(s1[i])+1)
   else:
      if ord(s2[i]) == 122:
          s3 += chr(97)
      else:
          s3 += chr(ord(s2[i])+1)
```

this is the full code for reference

```
s1 = input()
s2 = input()
n = int(input())
lst = []
for i in range(n):
    s3 = ''
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            if ord(s1[i]) == 122:
                s3 += chr(97)
            else:
                s3 += chr(ord(s1[i])+1)
        else:
            if ord(s2[i]) == 122:
                s3 += chr(97)
            else:
                s3 += chr(ord(s2[i])+1)
    lst.append(s3)
    s1 = s2
    s2 = s3
print(lst[n-3])
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way using list comprehensions to achieve the same. At least not with the assignments at the end of each iteration, e.g. `s1=s2; s2=s3`

Comment: @rv.kvetch but wouldn't a list comprehension possible just for the "for loop" I mentioned initially. I meant to achieve a list of individual characters of 's3' which I can then concatenate together while appending to 'lst'

Comment: Before converting it to a list comp, you'll need to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it out (e.g. `s = s1 if i % 2 == 0 else s2` then work with `s`). Also, turn the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_\(programming\)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) into constants (e.g. `SMALL_Z_ORD = 122` and `SMALL_A = chr(97)`).

Comment: Speaking of that, why are you comparing the `ord()` of a character against an integer instead of just comparing the character against a string? i.e. `if s1[i] == 'z'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I have no clue why you're doing it, rewriting that code as a comprehension is fairly straightforward:

```
s3 = ''.join(
    chr(97) if ord(t[i % 2]) == 122 else chr(ord(t[i % 2])+1) 
    for i, t in enumerate(zip(s1, s2))
)
```

Comment: how does this account for the `s1=s2; s2=s3` part at the end of each loop iteration above? that's the part that threw me off too, because I didn't understand that.

Comment: @rv.kvetch It doesn't. This is just the inner loop.

Comment: ohh, gotcha. for some reason I didn't see there were two for loops in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Writing comprehensions basically means that you move the append line, in this case string concatenation, to the front and everything else stays in the same order. I think Grismar's answer is better, but here is how you do it specifically as you asked.

```py
''.join(
    chr(97) if ord(s1[i]) == 122 else chr(ord(s1[i])+1) if i % 2 == 0
    else chr(97) if ord(s2[i]) == 122 else chr(ord(s2[i])+1)
    for i in range(len(s1))
)
```

See below:

```
>>> def f(s1, s2):
...     s3 = ''
...     for i in range(len(s1)):
...         if i % 2 == 0:
...             if ord(s1[i]) == 122:
...                 s3 += chr(97)
...             else:
...                 s3 += chr(ord(s1[i])+1)
...         else:
...             if ord(s2[i]) == 122:
...                 s3 += chr(97)
...             else:
...                 s3 += chr(ord(s2[i])+1)
...     return s3
... 
>>> f('123', '456')
'264'
>>> def g(s1, s2):
...     return ''.join(
...         chr(97) if ord(s1[i]) == 122 else chr(ord(s1[i])+1) if i % 2 == 0
...         else chr(97) if ord(s2[i]) == 122 else chr(ord(s2[i])+1)
...         for i in range(len(s1))
...     )
... 
>>> g('123', '456')
'264'
```

P.S. this level of nested if statements is way too complicated to include in code you share with other people (including your future self). Simplify, simplify, simplify!